# Used wrong client certificate for mutually authenticated certificates, how to reset?

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I'm currently experimenting with Mutually Authenticated certificates. I've created and installed my server certificate on a remote machine, and have correctly enforced SSL authentication for it. I've connected to that service through chrome and have been correctly challenged for a client certificate, however, I've selected the wrong one and I am now locked out, with 403's. I've tried using other browsers like firefox or ie, but they automatically try to use the wrong certificate.

How do you reset the use of a client certificate, without deleting that certificate, for a given domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing all browsers appears to reset this... this is not the most ideal solution but it does work.